# Inverting the composition of Inverses

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My teacher asked me to prove this equation. For functions $f$ and $g$, is $$(g^{-1} \circ f^{-1})^{-1} (x) = (f \circ g)(x)$$

always true?

Comment: It doesn't makes sense for all functions, $f,g$. You need more conditions.

Comment: Why does it not make sense? What kind of conditions? Please elaborate me.

Comment: It doesn't make sense when $f\circ g$ is not defined, at the very least.

Comment: Do you mean like I should define that (f∘g)(x) equal f(g(x))?

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$(f\circ g)(x)=y.$$

Then

$$(f^{-1}\circ f\circ g)(x)=f^{-1}(y)$$

and

$$(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}\circ f\circ g)(x)=(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})(y).$$

But $$(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}\circ f\circ g)(x)=x,$$ which shows that

$$(f\circ g)^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}.$$